# creating a named index on neo4j

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp

I am using neo4j php for a sample case which creates the indexes and adds the nodes to them

```
$client = new Client();
$actors = new NodeIndex($client, 'actors');
$juhichawla = $client->makeNode()->setProperty('name', 'Juhi Chawla')->save();
$actors->add($juhichawla, 'name', $juhichawla->getProperty('name'));
```

and i can see this index by looking at the data by REST API

```
:GET /db/data/index/node/

{
  "actors": {
    "template": "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/actors/{key}/{value}",
    "provider": "lucene",
    "type": "exact"
  }
}
```

Now i bulk loaded a number of actors, can i use the same index to index them as well, I really don't have an idea how to add indexing(named index of actors) to them, the neo4jphp code i use to find nodes is only helpful if you have named index to your data.

```
$from = 'shahrukh khan';
$client = new Client();
$actors = new NodeIndex($client, 'actors');

$fromNode = $actors->findOne('name', $from);        
f (!$fromNode) {
echo "$from not found\n";
exit(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, [here is the documentation on neo4j indexes](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/query-schema-index.html) and [here's the relevant docs for php](https://github.com/jadell/neo4jphp/wiki/Indexes).

So that documentation suggests your code is going to look something like this:

```
$nameIndex = new Everyman\Neo4j\Index\NodeIndex($client, 'actors');
$nameIndex->save();
```

Comment: But how do I search the contents if i already have indexes on them, but not named index as you just showed, can one create an instance of an index which is on the server, I guess I am making myself clear.

Comment: In general if you create an index, then you can use cypher and it will exploit the index automatically.  Named indexes need to be invoked by name in a cypher `start` clause.  But if you use schema indexes then just query as normal.